# libcudart and local build of gcc link against wrong glibc

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, cuda, glibc

I am trying to get CUDA5 to work on a shared cluster.

When I invoke the local gcc to build large applications it works just fine. When I use the CUDA wrapper I get an error saying that it can't find certain parts of glib.

Why is CUDA looking at `/lib64/libc.so.6`, if I specified the local gcc library directory?

```
[uid002@n001 cuda5test]$ ldd /home/ex/uid002/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so
/home/ex/uid002/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/ex/uid002/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff277ff000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5328da6000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5328b89000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5328981000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /home/ex/uid002/gcc/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f532867d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f53283f8000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/ex/uid002/gcc/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f53281e3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5327e67000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000335ae00000)
```

And

```
[uid002@n001 cuda5test]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/ex/uid002/cuda/lib64:/home/ex/uid002/gmp/lib:/home/ex/uid002/mpfr/lib:/home/ex/uid002/mpc/lib:/home/ex/uid002/gcc/lib64
```

I have tried to reinstall the CUDA package, and this was no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> libcudart.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found

This error means that the `libcudart.so` library was linked on a system with `glibc-2.14` or later. You can *only* use that library if your system (both at link time and at runtime) has `glibc` version >= 2.14.  Your system does not satisfy prerequisite for `libcudart.so`. You'll have to use older version of `libcudart.so`, or upgrade your system.

(Be careful: upgrading `glibc` incorrectly is a *sure* way to render the system un-bootable.)

> Why is CUDA looking at /lib64/libc.so.6, if I specified the local gcc library directory?

`Glibc` is not part of `GCC` distribution, and is completely independent. "local gcc library directory" is unlikely to have `libc.so` in it.